# Error when adding style to GeoServer through SLD using SVG symbol

Tags: svg, geoserver, qgis, sld

I am trying to create a new style for my point layer which uses an SVG symbol. On trying to validate the style using the SLD file generated from QGIS, I get the following error:

Parsing failed for ExternalGraphic: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: x

Below is my SLD file, is there anything obvious that is giving me this error?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>polling_stations</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>polling_stations</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Single symbol</se:Name>
          <se:PointSymbolizer>
            <se:Graphic>
              <se:ExternalGraphic>
                <se:OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="X:/FunGis/Tools/Styles/svg/polling_stations.svg"/>
                <se:Format>image/svg+xml</se:Format>
              </se:ExternalGraphic>
              <se:Size>8.5</se:Size>
              <se:Displacement>
                <se:DisplacementX>0</se:DisplacementX>
                <se:DisplacementY>-4</se:DisplacementY>
              </se:Displacement>
            </se:Graphic>
          </se:PointSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X is not a known protocol. Presumably you want [file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)